# Deshabilitar select dinamico dentro de ng-repeat con $index

Tags: html, angularjs

Tengo un problema desde hace dias es que tengo unos select que estan dentro de un ng-repeat. Necesito que al seleccionar uno se desactiven los demas pero no he logrado esto con nada.

Los select estan dentro de un ng- repeat el cual para poder diferenciarlos uno de otro uso $index, cabe destacar que tengo un ng-repeat anidado.

Este es mi codigo:

```js
vm.inUse = [];
  vm.isDisabled = function(name) {
    return vm.inUse.indexOf(name) !== -1;
  }

    vm.update = function(index) {


         if(index === vm.datoss){

                return true;

              }
              else {


                return false;
              }

              

    }

    vm.yourChecker = function(index) {
              

         
            vm.test = 0;
            vm.cont = Object.keys(vm.mon);

             for (var i = 0; i < vm.cont.length; i++) {

                
                
              } 


              if(index === 1){

                return true;

              }
              else {


                return false;
              }
           
            angular.forEach(vm.cont, function(value){
      
              vm.test = vm.test+ 1;

               if(index === 2){

                return true;

              }
              else {


                return false;
              }
      
              });


        }
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-5" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0">
  <div class="panel panel-default panel-table be-loading" ng-class="{'be-loading-active': vm.loading_users}">
      <div class="panel-heading">
                Premios
            <!--    <h4 class="text-right"><strong>Colecciones restantes:
              <span ng-show="vm.selectedInvoice.premios_restantes > 0">{{ vm.selectedInvoice.premios_restantes }}</span>
              <span ng-show="vm.selectedInvoice.premios_restantes <= 0">0</span></strong></h4>
            <h5 class="text-right"><strong>Colecciones: {{ vm.form.cantidad}}</strong></h5>
        -->
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <table  class="table table-striped table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
             
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat-start="premio in vm.gifts track by premio[0].tipo.id" ng-repeat-end>
              <td  class="cell-detail" style="text-align: center; cursor:pointer;">
                {{premio[0].tipo.tipo}}
                {{vm.test1}}
              </td >
              
                <td class="cell-detail" style="text-align: center; cursor:pointer;">

                <ol class="nya-bs-select" size="6" title="No seleccionado" style="padding:0; width: 100%"
                    ng-disabled="vm.estado === false || vm.yourChecker($index) || vm.isDisabled($index)"
                    ng-model="vm.form.selects.premio[$index]"
                    ng-change="vm.update($index)"
                    
                    required>
                  <li nya-bs-option="option in premio"  data-value="option.id" >
                    <a  ng-click="vm.logP(option.id, option.tipo.tipo, option.opcion_premio, option.tipo.valor);">
                      {{option.opcion_premio}}

                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ol>

              </td> 
              
             
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
       
      </div>
```

Eso es lo que he probado de distintas maneras pero no lo logro, ayuda por favor

Comment: se desactiva seleccionando una opción en concreto o con cualquier opción?

Comment: Quiero desactivar toda la lista, por ejemplo tengo 5 select, que al seleccionar uno de esos 5 los otros 4 se desactiven. No las opciones sino el select como tal, que no pueda seleccionar ninguna opcion de los otro 4 desactivados.

Comment: Puedes desactivar varios componentes a la vez con el fieldset. Intenta: `<fieldset ng-disable="variable"> .. selects </fieldset>`. Recuerda que la `variable` debe de calcularse para saber si alguno de los selects tiene un valor seleccionado, para esto, puedes hacer una función que valide los valores de los select o directamente una sola variable (puesto que al seleccionar uno, se deshabilitan los otros)